# MS VS компилирует exe "как подозрительное ПО"

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Добрый день.
Поставил систему DeepIN на VMware и появилось необходимость запустить сторонний .exe на системе, который написан мной (на C# в MS VS 2016 под .net 4.5)….
при первом клике, как положено создает бутылку, а дальше просто ничего не происходит… пробовал собирать экзешник и как самостоятельный и как установщик, во всех версиях и релиз и дебаг всегда одно и то же…. Причем всю официальные exe-файлы запускаются как надо и без проблем.
Подозрение, что тут все-таки дело на этапе сборки самого экзешника на вижуал студио, но как и что изменить для необходимого «заработало» — пока не приходит в голову… Так как при запуске экзешника на любом другой винде, он сперва указывает, что ПО подозрительно..
вот и появляется вопрос, на этапе компиляции этот фактор убрать можно, и если да то как?

Comment: Очевидно, что это реакция на действия приложения, которые могут ассоциироваться с вредоносным ПО. Больше без информации о самом приложении сказать нечего.

Comment: приложение подключается к ms sql, является оболочкой для БД

Comment: Значит что-то оно делает "не так, как положено приличному приложению", может хук какой подозрительный использовали или еще что. Вариантов слишком много. Попробуйте локализовать проблему и найти, какой именно фрагмент кода приводит к такой реакции систем безопасности. В моей практике был случай, когда антивирус реагировал на лямбду в событии WinForms вместо обычного метода. Тут где-то попадался вопрос с аналогичной ситуацией при использовании полно-экранного режима. В общем надо руками смотреть и пробовать.

Comment: Вас понял. Пожалуй начну с коммента всех соединений на внешние сервера и системных таймеров и методом исключения буду искать...